# Access to device light sensor readings (als) and display backlight level

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Would anyone know how to access the ambient light sensor (als) readings and display backlight level in Windows Phone 8? I would also like to access the display backlight level for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Windows Phone to access brightness sensor readings.

For Windows Store apps you can use [LightSensor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor) class:

```cs
LightSensor sensor = LightSensor.GetDefault();
LightSensorReading reading = sensor.GetCurrentReading();
```